# How can i increase the line size in ggplot2 geom_freqpoly?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I am having trouble getting the line sizes in my freqpoly plot a little thicker. When I use `aes(size = 1, ...)`, the lines become way to thick and "1" is not interpreted as the size in millimeters.

Here's the code for my plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = test4) + geom_freqpoly(aes(size= 4, x=value, color = variable), binwidth = 25, boundary=-0.5)  +
  ggtitle("Freqpoly plot") + labs(y = "Count", x="Length") +
  scale_color_brewer("Species", palette = "Set2") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,4000,500), labels = c("0", "500","1000","1500","2000","2500",
                                                          "3000","3500",">4000"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1400,100)) +
  theme_linedraw(base_size = 18)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(25,15,15,15,"pt")), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(15,15,15,15,"pt"))) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

And test looks like:

```
   variable value
1    C.rip   574
2    C.rip   269
3    C.rip   111
4    C.rip    79
5    C.rip   504
6    C.rip   252
```

The plots end up like this, `(with aes(size..)` and without:

[image]
[image]

Most of the answers I found for other questions were only for `geom_line` or `geom_point`.

Whats the correct way to increase line size here?

Comment: For this second plot, where you don't put size in your `aes`, where *do* you put size for the freqpoly?

Comment: Nowhere, I used the default.

Comment: Okay, so you need to set the size to what you want. You can give a size argument inside `geom_freqpoly` but outside `aes`. Try `size = 1`, see how you like it, then adjust the size if you need to

Comment: Camille is correct, setting size needs to be done outside `aes`, e.g.: `+ geom_freqpoly(aes(x=value, color = variable), size= 4, binwidth = 25, boundary=-0.5)`

Comment: Thank you, I knew I had to be missing something trivially easy here - just couldnt figure out what. :)